# Find the value of a <TD> and retrive it into input box

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some trouble to get the text in a  and put it in an  Box, here you can find a small example.
The idea is when the user click the "Select"  it put the code from inside the

```
<td> @Html.DisplayFor(Mod => Item.Item.Custumer_code) <td/>
```

in the Input input with the Custumercode ID.
here is the code:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
<input class="form-control"
       placeholder="Entre a custumer code"
       id="Custumercode" 
       name="Custumercode"/>
</div>
<table class="table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Costumer Code</th>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>Costumer Name</th>
        <th>Email </th>
        <th>Tel </th>
    </tr>
</thead>

@foreach (var Item in Model)
{
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(Mod => Item.Custumer_code) </td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(Mod => Item.custumer_name) </td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(Mod => Item.Email) </td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(Mod => Item.Tel) </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">
                Select
            </button>
        </td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
}
</table>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click','.btn',function(){
 var customer = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
 $('#Custumercode').val(customer );
});
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zuv5r/)

Comment: you copied my answer as variable customerCode does not exist in your code :)

Comment: Yes this is working verry goood thank you very mutch

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.btn').click(function(){
     var customerCode = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
     $('#Custumercode').val(customerCode );
    });
});
```